# short URL through htaccess file in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website http://sharenotes.xyz/.
In this website users can save and share quick notes to others users.
There is a unique note id for each note. (id can only contain [0-9A-Za-z_] charachters).
Unique note id is present in the url `http://sharenotes.xyz/hithere`.
In this case **hithere** is the unique note id.
In actual the url is like
http://sharenotes.xyz/index.php?id=hithere.
My folder structure looks like -
[image: folder structure]
and index.php file is present in public folder.
What will be the content of the `.htaccess` file to short the url from http://sharenotes.xyz/index.php?id=hithere to http://sharenotes.xyz/hithere and in which folder should I place that .htaccess file ?
I know php but I am new in htaccess file (stored in public_html folder).

#### UPDATE

I was forget to tell you something that -
There is folder named as public which servers all user accessible files.
So I have also hide the name public from the url throught .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

That's why you wouldn't see public in url.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the required rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ /public/index.php?id=$1 [END]
```

Best is to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. Only if you do not have access to that, then you should use a distributed configuration file, often called ".htaccess". But that comes with a number of disadvantages. If you decide to use one, then place it inside the top folder of your hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, so here inside the "public_html" folder.

Obviously the rewriting modules needs to be loaded into the apache http server for this. And if you are using a distributed configuration file then you also need to enable the interpretation of such files for that location (read about the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation of the http server).

Most likely you will need to add further rewriting rules to sort out requests to other resources.

---

UPDATE

Considering your comments and the additional information you now added to describe your actual situation this variant probably is close to what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond /public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond /public%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [END]

RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ /public/index.php?id=$1 [END]
```

Comment: Sorry I forget one thing to mention. So please read my updated section. Then reanswer !

Comment: So you need to combine both rule, right? I am sure you will figure that one out...

Comment: Indeed. That is true.

Comment: the above rule which gives you is not working. 404 error because browser is looking for a file **hithere** (i guess)

Comment: The above rule is working perfectly fine. But now, that your actual situation is actually different you need to adjust it. As said: you need to _combine both rules.

Comment: Thanks for the solution It is working now. But the above rule (in your answer) must be in public folder then only works.

Comment: Please update your answer where to place this rule (public folder).

Comment: No, that rule does not have to be implemented in the "/public" folder. As already mentioned you need to adapt it so that it works together with the other rules you already have implemented. Using multiple distributed configuration files will raise the disadvantages you gain by using such files. The more such files the slower your http server will get. So I would strongly advise not to use such files or if you cannot get around that to use only one such file place in your http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.